# Office 365 MyFiles API - How to get the Folder object using Id string from One Drive

Tags: api, office365

I am having no joy in getting a specific folder object from OneDrive. I am look to produce a breadcrumb trail based on the folder user is viewing.

To kick things off I am instantiating `SharePointClient` which is targeting users root folder like so:

```
var spClient = await AuthenticationHelper.EnsureSharePointClientCreatedAsync("MyFiles");
```

Then I am fetching root files and folders like so:

```
var rootFiles = await spClient.Files.ExecuteAsync();
var files = rootFiles.CurrentPage;
```

If user clicks into a folder I am fetching that folders files and folders like so:

```
var folderFiles = await spClient.Files[selectedItemID].ToFolder().Children.ExecuteAsync();
var files = folderFiles.CurrentPage;
```

Where `selectedItemID` in this case is just the `Id` property of the folder the user has selected.

As for the **problem** that I am having is getting folder object itself. I keep getting this error:

```
Expected a relative URL path without query or fragment.
Parameter name: entitySetName
```

When I try to execute one of the following:

```
// first attempt
var folder = await spClient.Files[selectedItemID].ToFolder().ExecuteAsync();

// second attempt - which is the same as first attempt with use of GetById()
var folder = await spClient.Files.GetById(selectedItemID).ToFolder().ExecuteAsync();

// third attempt - which is the same as second attempt without chaining
var thisItemFetcher = spClient.Files.GetById(selectedItemID);
var thisFolderFetcher = thisItemFetcher.ToFolder();
var myFolder = await thisFolderFetcher.ExecuteAsync();
var folder = myFolder as Microsoft.Office365.SharePoint.FileServices.Folder;
```

If I was to execute any of these attempts while looking for a file I would get the file object no problem.

Of course I tried looking up this error but I didn't get anywhere.

What I am trying to do is fairly simple. All I need is to return a list of simple objects

```
{
    FolderID = folder.Id,
    FolderName = folder.Name,
}
```

for the folder user is currently viewing and each respective parent right up to the root folder.

I know I can do this recursively based on `folder.ParentReference.Id` property.

Now you might be thinking why can't you just request a list of files and folders from the folder user is viewing? Sure based on any returned file or folder `.ParentReference.Id` you can do your recursion. Well the answer to that question is exactly that: What happens if the folder is empty?

Can someone shed some light on this simple yet not so straightforward problem I am having here.

According to [SkyDrive Folder object docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn631836.aspx):

```
A Folder object can be returned as part of:
/FOLDER_ID/files
/me/skydrive/files
/me/skydrive/shared/files
/USER_ID/skydrive/files
/ALBUM_ID/files
```

But I am not sure if this also applies to Office 365 OneDrive.

Looking at the latest [OneDrive API](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/get.htm) they seem to use completely different request structure:

`GET /drive/items/{item-id}`

My `SarePointClient.Drive` does not expose `Items` collection.

For those curious of you I am using [Microsoft Office 365 My Files Library v1.0.22](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office365.SharePoint/) to access OneDrive.

Answer (score 0):

The document SkyDrive Folder object is using service endpoint https://apis.live.net.

The document OneDrive API  is using service endpoints:
https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0 (OneDrive)
or https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0 (OneDrive for Business).

In this case, you should use the latest .NET OneDrive SDK: [OneDrive .NET SDK 1.1.29](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OneDriveSDK)

> How to get the Folder object using Id string from One Drive

GET /drive/items/{item-id}

```
oneDriveClient.Drive.Items["{item_id}"]
```

Comment: As I mentioned what I am actually using is MyFiles library for MS Office 365. So, instead I have ``SharePointClient`` which exposes users OneDrive to me via ``SharePointClient.Files`` collection. My question specifically asks how to achieve ``oneDriveClient.Drive.Items["{item_id}"]`` with ``SharePointClient.Files.GetById("{item_id}")``.

Comment: @iiminov, according to the document, the Office 365 Files API has been deprecated. For OneDrive and OneDrive for Business development, use the OneDrive API. That's why I suggest you using the .NET OneDrive SDK.